# How to write a regular expression to extract data from response in JMeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I need to extract an ID from the response of an API call in JMeter. The response looks something like this:

```
"sessionId":"Edhgjhsbdjkkmsdsd-dlkmsdl.Mkhsdiufhskjndjsbsbd.iusdhfjsnkdnsd"
```

I only need to extract the last string between `.` and `"` i.e. `iusdhfjsnkdnsd`.

I've tried writing this regular expression:

```
"sessionId":"(.+?)\.(.+?)\.(.+?)"
```

I've set the template value to `$3$` so only the third value is picked but it doesn't work. Nothing is captured using this regex.

Comment: Saying *"it doesen't work"* tells us nothing. What result do you get? Please [edit] the question to give full details.

Comment: I see that in the regex you have "sessionID" and in the data you have "sessionId" maybe that is the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, all you need to do is to escape dots with backslashes like:

```
"sessionId":"(.+?)\.(.+?)\.(.+?)"
```

because dot is a [meta-character](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars) which means "any character" and if you want JMeter's regex engine to treat is as a dot - you need to escape it properly.

Also you can consider using [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-boundary-extractor), all you need to do is to set "left" and "right" boundaries and JMeter will capture everything in-between